# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using python tutorial

Tags: python, numpy, face-recognition, pca

Does any body have a tutorial for Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using python including code and explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Modular Toolkit for Data Processing might be helpful:
http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks matt but I need to understand the implementation and build my own code not a ready to use tool

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916837/how-to-get-the-1st-principal-component-by-pca-using-python

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccommend the [Principal Component Analysis in 3 Simple Steps](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_pca_in_3_steps.html) by Sebastian Raschka.

> Principal Component Analysis (PCA) is a simple yet popular and useful linear transformation technique that is used in numerous applications, such as stock market predictions, the analysis of gene expression data, and many more. In this tutorial, we will see that PCA is not just a “black box”, and we are going to unravel its internals in 3 basic steps.

It has a nice and short intro on PCA, examples with great images, makes use of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), and its made entirely on Python.