# How to get the 1st Principal Component by PCA using Python?

Tags: python, pca

I have a set of 2D vectors presented in a `n*2` matrix form.

I wish to get the 1st principal component, i.e. the vector that indicates the direction with the largest variance.

I have found [a rather detailed documentation](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/pca_docs.shtml) on this from Rice University.

Based on this, I have imported the data and done the following:

```
import numpy as np

dataMatrix = np.array(aListOfLists)   # Convert a list-of-lists into a numpy array.  aListOfLists is the data points in a regular list-of-lists type matrix.
myPCA = PCA(dataMatrix)   # make a new PCA object from a numpy array object
```

**Then how may I get the 3D vector that is the 1st Principal Component?**

Comment: Eigenvectors for 2D input data **must be 2D**, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA gives only 2d vecs from 2d data.

Look at the picture in Wikipedia [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis):
starting with a point cloud (dataMatrix) like that, and using `matplotlib.mlab.PCA`,
`myPCA.Wt[0]` is the first PC, the long one in the picture.

Comment: So are you sure that `myPCA.Wt[0]` is the first PC? I have a bunch of data sets. As I perform PCA to each data set and plot the 1st PC of each data set, I always end up with only 4 vectors. I am expecting many, since I plot the 1st PC of a lot of data sets. It seems to be due to **some unknown scaling** behind...

Comment: Back up, *look* at the datasets. I'd suggest plotting all the vectors to Wt[0] and Wt[1], together with the point clouds (after PCA centres them). (What's N, what's "a bunch" ?)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [Principal component analysis in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730600/principal-component-analysis-in-python)

Or you could have a look at scikit-learn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: how are they similar please? I didn't see any similarity there. What I want is very simple, just the 1st component. I suppose it is only a few lines of codes. Please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious from your example that you are using `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` but if so, the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=mlab#matplotlib.mlab) states that the returned object has an attribute *Wt*, which is "the weight vector for projecting a numdims point or array into PCA space".

`PCA` returns the eigenvalues in descending order (you can tell by looking at the *fracs* attribute of the returned object). So the first principal component (first eigenvector) will be the first row of `Wt`.

As noted by @denis, your eigenvectors will be 2D (not 3D) since your input data are 2D.